# Counting number of roots inside a circle, using Rouche's theorem,

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, residue-calculus

Using the Argument Principle and applying Rouche's Theorem, I know that there are 6 zeroes of the polynomial $$z^{10}-6z^6+3z^4-1$$ inside the unit circle $|z|=1$, no zeroes inside $|z|=1/2$, but I'm not sure how to compute the number of zeroes inside the circle $|z|=3/2$.

The best I can do, so far, is to compute the number of zeroes inside the larger circle $|z|=2$.  I get $10$ zeroes.

So, I know this polynomial must have $10-6 = 4$ zeroes ...between $|z|=1$ and |z|=2.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**.  Consider $f(x)$ where $x$ is real, $1\le x\le2$.  Also $f(iy)$ where $1\le y\le2$.

Comment: using your hint shows that f(x) goes from negative to positive as x (real) runs from 1 to 2.  So, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, we pick up a zero on the real line between 1 and 2.  Similarly, f(iy) goes from positive to negative, as y runs from 1 to 2.  So we pick up another zero along the imaginary axis.  Finally, since this complex polynomial has real coefficients, its roots come in conjugate pairs - symmetric points with respect to the real axis.  Here's where I'm currently stuck at:

Comment: Would the root along the real axis, which is symmetric to itself, with respect to the real axis, not have a conjugate root to pair up with?  Also, now that I've found two roots, using your hint, and assuming they both come in conjugate pairs, then I've now found the four roots outside of |z|=1.  How do I be precise about the number of roots inside |z| = 3/2?  Repeating your hint for the case 3/2 < x < 2, and 3/2 < y < 2 ...doesn't seem like a wise move.  Thanks,

Comment: actually, I applied your hint for the case 3/2 < x < 2 and for 3/2 < y < 2.  I now see that there are no zeroes along the real axis from 3/2 to 2, but we pick up one root along the imaginary axis from y=3/2 to y=2.  Using the symmetry argument as before, we know there is another root along the imaginary axis, conjugate to this root that we picked up.  So, the conclusion is that there are a total of 8 roots inside |z| = 3/2, with 6 roots inside |z|=1, and 2 roots between |z|=3/2 and |z|=2, giving us all 10 roots of the polynomial.  What do you think @David?  Thanks,

Comment: hmmm...a little confused, @David, since I thought I had just solved it. but, yea, i definitely got a sign change on the real line, when i applied your first hint for 1<x<2.  but when I applied the hint for 3/2<x<2, I did not get a sign change along the real line..

Comment: Sounds pretty good, but do you have a complete argument for eight roots inside $|z|=3/2$?  You have two roots outside and seven inside but I couldn't see where you mentioned the eighth.

Comment: Another thing to notice: besides real coefficients, there is something else special about your polynomial.  (These problems are always like detective work, looking for all the clues you can find.)

Comment: I think I might have it now, @David.  It has real coefficients, as well as only even-powered terms.  I picked up a root along the imaginary axis from 3/2 to 2.  Its conjugate is also a root, so this gives 2 roots between |z|=3/2 and |z|=2. Since there were 6 roots inside |z|=1, and 10 roots inside |z|=2, there must be 8 roots inside |z|=3/2.  The two roots that need mentioning are both real roots, which get picked from somewhere between 1<x<3/2 (since there was no sign change from 3/2 to 2 on the real line, there couldn't have been any real roots in that interval).

Comment: If this is indeed correct, I have one lingering confusion, if you wouldn't mind helping me with:  I thought the roots should come in conjugate pairs (for real coefficient, complex valued polynomials), so...how come I get two real roots that are symmetric with respect to the imaginary axis?  Of course, I'm pretty sure the answer is that there were only even-powered terms in our polynomial, but still, that seems to break the definition of conjugate pairs of roots ... (unless I have my definitions wrong for the different outcomes of roots).  Thanks,

Comment: sorry, I meant to say that the two real roots get picked up from somewhere between 1<x<3/2 , and from -1<x<-3/2.

Comment: That sounds pretty complete now.  Having conjugate pairs doesn't mean that a real root must be a double root.  For example $z-1$ obviously only has one root.

Comment: Ok, got it now.  Thanks so much for your help, @David.  Have a great night.